# how to group historical data in cumulocity cep query

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper, cumulocity

I have to group the last week data per day .I was able to retrieve  the historical data every 10 sec but not able to group by date

```
insert into AllMeasurementsOfWeek 
select findAllMeasurementByFragmentTypeAndSourceAndTimeBetween('Avg_Load','764697',(current_timestamp().minus(7 day)).toDate(),current_timestamp().toDate()) as m,current_timestamp().toDate() as time
from pattern[every timer:interval(10 sec)];


@Name("Occupancy")
@Resilient 
select  * from AllMeasurementsOfDay ;
```

---

Above code will output the response as below

```
{
  "m": [
    {
      "time": "2018-04-14T17:03:14.000+02:00",
      "id": "17345353",
      "source": "764697",
      "type": "Avg_Load",
      "Average_Load": {
        "loading_time": {
          "unit": "min",
          "value": 25
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "time": "2018-04-15T17:03:14.000+02:00",
      "id": "17345194",
      "source": "764697",
      "type": "Avg_Load",
      "Avg_Load": {
        "loading_time": {
          "unit": "min",
          "value": 25
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "time": "2018-04-15T17:03:14.000+02:00",
      "id": "17345194",
      "source": "764697",
      "type": "Avg_Load",
      "Avg_Load": {
        "loading_time": {
          "unit": "min",
          "value": 25
        }
      }
    }
]
```

How should i access the above response and group by date ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you directly query the day you want? So doing 7 queries (one per day).

Otherwise whenever you do a query to the API with a date range it will be sorted by date. So you can also just add a small expression (like javascript) to split it into the 7 days. Should be pretty simple as the response is already sorted by date.